# Reduce line-spacing in acronyms with hyperref

Tags: hyperref, line-spacing, acronyms

I'm using:

```
\documentclass[12pt,titlepage]{article}

\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage{datatool}
\usepackage[style=altlist,nonumberlist,numberedsection,acronym,toc,xindy]{glossaries}
\makeglossaries
\makeindex

\newacronym[description={\glslink{acronyms}{this is an acronym}}]{acronyms}{ACRONYMS}{"acronyms"}

\begin{document}

\printglossaries

blablabla \gls{acronyms} blablabla

\end {document}
```

Now, the problem is that in the `.pdf` it appears as:

[image]

Too much space and too much lines, therefore too much pages wasted!

How to get rid of this?

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure to correctly understand, but it seems to me that you want your acronym description in the same line.

Note that you are using the `altlist` style when loading `glossaries` package, which belongs to the 'List Styles' type. These style types use the `description` environment; moreover with `altlist` the description starts on the line following the name and that's why you have your acronym printed over two lines.

If you remove `style=altlist` you get:

[image]

Hope this is what you were looking for.

Comment: @elisa The best way to say thank you is to upvote good answers and to accept the one you think is best.

Answer (score 2):

Package `glossaries` provides many styles for the acronym list, see Chapter ["15 Glossary Styles"](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/glossaries/glossaries-user.pdf), examples:

- `style=list`  (default, if you omit this option)
- `style=long3col` (set as `longtable in three columns`)
- `style=index` (similar to an index)
- ...